# VARIANT export/import C++ DLL SAFEARRAY

Tags: c++, vba, dll, variant, safearray

I know that this topic is quite popular. However, I'd like to solve a simple problem... My target is to create a DLL in C++ able to import and export data matrices from VB (Excel or other programs). I read in some blogs that a common way to do that is to use the `SAFEARRAY`s.

So, I created the following C++ code:

```cpp
VARIANT _stdcall ReadArrayVBA_v1(VARIANT *Input0) {
    double dm = 0, rm = 0;

    //OUTPUT DATA DEFINITION
    VARIANT v;
    SAFEARRAYBOUND Dim[1];
    Dim[0].lLbound = 0; Dim[0].cElements = 4;
    v.vt = VT_R8;
    v.parray = SafeArrayCreate(VT_R8, 1, Dim);
    //==============================================

    SAFEARRAY* pSafeArrayInput0 = NULL; //Define a pointer SAFEARRAY Type
    pSafeArrayInput0 = *V_ARRAYREF(Input0); 

    long lLBound = -1, lUBound = 1; //Preset dimension
    SafeArrayGetLBound(pSafeArrayInput0, 1, &lLBound); 
    SafeArrayGetUBound(pSafeArrayInput0, 1, &lUBound);

    long CntElements = lUBound - lLBound + 1;
    long Index[1];
    for (int i=0; i<CntElements; i++){
        Index[0] = i;
        SafeArrayGetElement(pSafeArrayInput0, Index, &dm);

        rm = dm + 1;

        SafeArrayPutElement(v.parray, Index, &rm);
    }
    return v;
}
```

It compiles and I call from VBA Excel in the following manner:

```vb
Private Declare Function ReadArrayVBA_v1 Lib "[PATH]\VARIANTtest.dll" (ByRef Input0 As Variant) As Variant

Sub VBACall()
    Dim InputR0(1 To 4) As Variant
    Dim vResult1 As Variant

    InputR0(1) = 2
    InputR0(2) = 20
    InputR0(3) = 200
    InputR0(4) = 240

    vResult1 = ReadArrayVBA_v1(InputR0)    
End Sub
```

The function gives me back values such as 1.2E-305 and similar. Why?

Comment: First, don't use VARIANT directly, use `_variant_t` or `CComVariant` or another wrapper. Second, vartype of your return should be `VT_ARRAY|VT_R8`. Third you haven't checked the vartype of the input variant.

Comment: Ok for checking, ok for VT_ARRAY|VT_R8, but I don't get where to use _variant_t or CComVariant...

Comment: That's just advice. It's not wrong to use VARIANT, it's just harder to do it right.

Comment: Ah Ok... I try to read something. Could you suggest me?

Comment: Why don't you just do the job in VBA? It's a perfectly good language.

Comment: Oh yes... I could, but I'd like to try in C++ in order to be more efficient with big data volumes. This dumm example is only an example. My idea is to scale it and manage big matrices. I already have the VBA version of the full program, but it is very slow...

Comment: VBA is a compiled language, it's likely that you can make it faster by using correct datatypes, e.g. arrays of double in place of arrays of variant.

Comment: You make a hard assumption that the array contains *double* elements.  But it doesn't, it contains variant elements.  And they are not variants that are double.  You need to look at SAFEARRAY.fFeatures to verify that FADF_VARIANT is turned on.  And convert the variant values with VariantChangeType() so you can access VARIANT.dblVal

Comment: Or change your declare statement so the VBA can only pass an arg() As Double